# Perl/CGI not working for /home/user/cgi but working for /var/www/cgi-bin

Tags: perl, cgi, centos7, apache2.4, selinux

My Server is
    CentOS7
    Apache 2.4
    SELinux enabled.

Perl/CGI is working for **/var/www/cgi-bin** directory but not working for **/home/user/cgi** directory.

error-log shows the following errors for test.pl:

```
[Fri Jan 08 19:53:05.725795 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 7311] [client *:33769] End of script output before headers: test.pl
[Fri Jan 08 19:54:10.981964 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 7314] [client *:33770] End of script output before headers: test.pl
```

perl -w test.pl shows no error on command line.

SELinux settings for /home/user/cgi directory is

```
drwxr-xr-x.  4 unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0 user user   83 Jan  8 20:05 .
drwxr-xr-x. 11 unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 user user 4096 Jan  7 12:08 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0 user user   90 Jan  8 20:05 test.pl
```

Content of test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
print "Hello\n\n";
```

httpd.conf

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
Require all granted
DirectoryIndex index.pl index.cgi
```

Link to httpd related sebool options:
[sebool](http://business-impact-solutions.com/getsebool-httpd.txt)
Greatly appreciate help...

Comment: Is there anything in the Apache error log? (Might be something like `/var/log/apache2/error.log`).

Comment: I did not see anything relating to this error in /var/log/httpd/error_log.

Nevertheless, here is the link to the log contents.  Maybe i have missed something! : [link] (http://business-impact-solutions.com/error_log_2016-08-01.txt)

Comment: maybe it's the old file buffering thing? try putting   $|=1; before any of the print statements in your script.

Comment: No, `$|=1;` did not solve the issue

Comment: I assume the section of httpd.conf you showed is inside a `<Directory>` block. Which directory? (You need to show the configuration for both /var/www/cgi-bin and /home/user/cgi for us to be able to help.)

Comment: [httpd.conf](http://business-impact-solutions.com/httpd.conf.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

The problem was caused by this line:

```
SuexecUserGroup "#1000" "#1000"
```

Problem resolved once I removed that directive.